# Are other companies using social media like KLM's "meet & seat" program?

Tags: online-resources, socializing, klm

KLM has a [meet & seat program](https://www.klm.com/travel/be_en/prepare_for_travel/on_board/Your_seat_on_board/meet_and_seat.htm), where you can see if you have a linkedin or facebook connection in common, with the person sitting next to you. 
Are other companies utilizing social media in the same way?

Answer (score 4):

AirBaltic has a ["Seat Buddy" program](http://www.airbaltic.com/public/50335.html) where they let people choose to sit with other passengers with similar moods / interests.

Arguably, [Airtroductions](http://airtroductions.com/) has tried to get dating in flight happening, but it's dubious as to whether they ever properly got "off the ground".

[Planely](http://www.planely.com/) lets you reach out to other passengers on your flight too (although they also need to be planely members)

Finally, [WeMetonaPlane](http://wemetonaplane.com/) allows you to try and contact that special someone you made a connection with. Again, presumably relies on the other person using the site too...

Comment: I could be mistaken, but I think Thromby Air is a joke site, "thromby" being DVT...

Comment: @jogloran thanks, can't believe I missed that. Well spotted :)

Comment: AirBaltic link doesn't work